# Moving symfony2 htaccess file into vhost

Tags: mod-rewrite, symfony

I wanted to move .htaccess content into vhost for performance, and am trying to solve an issue.

This is in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

I tried this in Vhost:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
```

The problem is that second one redirects /app_dev.php/ controller to app.php and it shoud not, like in first example.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you activate rewriting with "RewriteEngine on" in your Vhost?

Comment: @MartinRothenberger Yes I did. Otherwise it would not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

From [RewriteCond Directive <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)**:**

> **REQUEST_FILENAME:**
>       The full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request, if this has already been determined by the server at the time REQUEST_FILENAME is referenced. Otherwise, such as when used **in virtual host context, the same value as REQUEST_URI**.

So what you are actually testing for is not a file has the path `/app_dev.php` which is not the absolute path i.e. without the `DocumentRoot` path prepended. So, you have to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /app.php [L]
```

- `^(.*)$` there is no need for this as you are just rewriting without consideration for URI.
- Flag `QSA` also not required as you are not manipulating any query string.

Comment: The script that I'm working with requires every request to go through app.php if request it not a file. but it will use app_dev.php if such file is present. I don't know how it does it but with the .htaccess file I posted above here's what happens: domain.com/test/something requests app.php and receives /test/something as Query string. /app_dev.php/test/something will request app_dev.php and sent /test/something as query string. For some reason. I dont know how it does that with just that .htaccess file.

Comment: what I had tried (second code block) and what you wrote does the same thing for me for some reason, and /app_dev.php/ is redirected to / and that's my problem, with original .htaccess it does not do that.

Comment: @Leo What other rules do you have in your htaccess?

Comment: That's the only thing in my .htaccess, and vhosts only has www to non www rewrite that you helped me with earlier.